# Select verificando uma condição

Tags: sql, sql-server

Preciso fazer um select onde é verificado uma condição.
Ex: Se o valor de um determinado campo for < 0 atribui a soma desse campo a coluna "`PerdaGerada`" caso contrario atribuir a coluna "`LucroGerado`".

Algo como mostrado abaixo:

```
SELECT TOP 10
       TBL.PRODUTO PRODUTO,
       COUNT(TBL.ID) AS QTD,

       SE TBL.VALORGANHO < = ENTAO SOMA DE VALOR GANHO VAI PRA COLUNA "PERDAGERADA"
       SE TBL.VALORGANHO > = ENTAO SOMA DE VALOR GANHO VAI PRA COLUNA "LUCROGERADO"


FROM TABELAVENDAS TBL
WHERE TBL.DATAEMISSAO BETWEEN '20150901' and '20150930' 
GROUP BY TBL.PRODUTO
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Comment: Dica: use `CASE`

Comment: fiz assim ... 
CASE WHEN (ACC.VALORGANHO < 0 SUM(ACC.VALORGANHO) AS PERDAGER ELSE SUM(ACC.VALORGANHO) AS ECONOMIAGER END

mais nao deu certo nao

Comment: tenta `CASE WHEN x THEN y WHEN w THEN z END AS "alias"`
Infelizmente não tem como fazer um alias dinâmico, até onde eu sei.

Comment: Não consegui desta  maneira ...

Answer (score 4):

Pra chegar nesse resultado você pode usar CASE

Exemplo:

```
 SELECT TOP 10 TBL.PRODUTO , COUNT(TBL.ID) AS QTD , 
 SUM(CASE WHEN TBL.VALORGANHO <= 0 THEN TBL.VALORGANHO ELSE 0 END) AS PERDAGERADA , 
 SUM(CASE WHEN TBL.VALORGANHO >= 0 THEN TBL.VALORGANHO ELSE 0 END) AS lUCROGERADO FROM TABELAVENDAS TBL
    WHERE TBL.DATAEMISSAO BETWEEN '20150901' and '20150930' 
    GROUP BY TBL.PRODUTO
    ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Comment: Diego, muito obrigado !!! sua resposta foi precisa !! Certinho !!

Comment: @AlvaroVieira fico feliz que tenha dado certo e ajudado !